# Is there a way to get back items after /clear command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used the /clear command, and I accidentally got rid of a **very** important book. Is there a way to get it back without having to rewrite it?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: You are simply can do it with the NBTExplorer program. First of all, you Open your save and check level.dat_old/Data/Player/Inventory if you can see Inventory items just copy this folder. Then you should paste this data to level.dat/Data/Player/Inventory and to playerdata/name.dat and to the playerdata/name.dat_old at the same way. Got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any mods, it's not possible. You'll have to rewrite the book then

If you have very specific or important items in your inventory, you should temporarily throw them on the ground or put them in a chest before using `/clear`.

Comment: I forgot the book was in my inventory. I should be more careful... I'm a noob

Answer (score 9):

You can try crashing/killing Minecraft as soon as possible after that happens by either holding down F3+C for 10 seconds or stopping `javaw.exe` in the task manager. Do not use the "X" icon or Alt+F4, since that triggers saving.

If you're really lucky, no autosave happened between your command and the exiting, that would mean that your inventory (and everything else in the world) resets to the state it was a few seconds ago.

Comment: Or flicking the power off on your computer? Both 10 secs f3+c and locating and quitting javaw seem very slow

Comment: That is funny.  I had the same thought.  Who knew, crash the game, could ever actually be a solution.

Comment: Shutting down stuff is often a good reaction in panic situations. If I mess up a Minecraft world, I immediately exit Minecraft, turn off internet, turn my laptop on, which has no internet by default, copy the old version of the synchronised file and turn internet on on it to synchronise that. If you have a virus that either copies itself or deletes/encrypts your files, you should immediately turn your computer off and disconnect all storage mediums. If a robot, production line or other machine does something unwanted, you stop it. If a program has a really bad error, it should crash.

Comment: I wouldn't. Mine usually autosaves, so all that'll do is just waste time.

Comment: You mean Minecraft? And yes, it autosaves, but only every few seconds, so if you immediately kill the process without giving it the chance to save (through task manager or F3+C, not the cross or the ingame button), you might be lucky.

Comment: To add some numbers to this: An autosave happens every 45 seconds, so if you take 1 second to realise what happened and 10 seconds to crash Minecraft with F3+C or to kill it with the task manager, the chance of successfully recovering your items with this strategy is 75%. That's with very fast reaction time, the probability linearly goes down to 0 over the next 34 seconds.

Comment: finding javaw.exe is a little slow so open command prompt and type "taskkill /f /im javaw.exe"

Comment: Nice timing for me to get an upvote notification on this, because yesterday my phone broke its SD card by suddenly turning off while writing to it. So no, @theonlygusti, do not suddenly cut power to your computer, ever, because it can corrupt any storage medium that it is currently writing to. BTW, on Linux, the process name is "`java`" and the insta-kill command is "`killall java`" (but that kills pretty much everything that runs with Java, so can have other side effects).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous answers, I'd like to give you a preventive measure:

Make use of the saved hotbars if you have an important item you don't want to loose. You can get back your saved hotbars at any time while in creative mode. Just make sure you don't override the important one.

To access saved hotbars, use X+number (load) or C+number (save) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth: using a Minecraft Forge Server on 1.20.1 of the game, I found that it saves a .dat_old file in the world folder under the playerdata subfolder.  Renaming the original .dat file for your user account to .dat_wiped and copying the .dat_old file to have the same name and extension as the original .dat file will for most intents and purposes revert your inventory to the previous state.  At least I don't notice any differences from what I had before the wipe at this time.

Answer (score 0):

#### A more technical solution:

1. Navigate to your save backup folder, pick the nearest one, open the folder `playerdata` and 2 files called `level.dat` and `level.dat_old`.
2. Delete the folder and files `playerdata`, `level.dat` and `level.dat_old` from your world.
3. Copy the `level.dat` and `level.dat_old` that you just opened into your world.

***Note***: Some of the world history might be deleted in the process.