# How do I recover deleted books from inventory in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died in my hardcore mode world that I really care about. and I changed myself to creative mode, grabbed my stuff, put it in a chest and made a new book explaining to my future self how I died and how long I survived for in case my future self curiously came into the world to see what it was.

After I finished writing the book I grabbed my book of coordinates from my chest that I created and wrote before I died. I decided to play around with the save toolbar hotkey (dumb idea) and went to try save my toolbar, but instead of pressing <kbd>C+6</kbd> like I meant to, I accidentally pressed <kbd>X+6</kbd>, which cleared my inventory completely because toolbar number 6 in the inventory was already previously empty, so it essentially replaced all my items with air.

My question here is, is there any way I can find and recover those 2 books in the world files or game files? I don't care what it takes to get those books back even if I have to mod the game, I just want a way to recover the books.

I don't really care much for the death book, just as long as I can get my coordinates back because they are extremely important to have.

Answer (score 1):

Your only chance would be to <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> out of the game (or crash it by other means) before it saves anything to your drive, so you have to do this as soon as possible. But you should use this approach with **caution**. In rare cases it could as well corrupt your game files and eventually destroy your saved world.

If it's already too late for that there is no known way of getting your books back. 
There is currently **nothing** in the game that **can restore a cleared inventory** by normal means.

For the future:

Make backups. Save a copy of your world somewhere else and doing so on a regular basis can save you a lot of headache.

Comment:  OK thankyou for the info I'll leave the question up for now in case anyone else might have an answer. Also I'll find out when I send this comment but I think when I downloaded the app for arqade on my phone I might have accidentally made a new account (so many accidents) so I might not be commenting right now as the original poster but rather as a different Liam.

Comment: OK yeah it was the right account

Comment: I can't alt f4 crash the game, I already quit the world and turned off the computer, I was hoping I wouldn't have to keep the world on

Comment: You can crash the game by holding F3+C. Using Alt+F4 closes the game rather than to crash it. (I´m not sure if that is relevant though, because I am unsure when and how often the game saves)

Comment: @Mr.Bear Alt + F4 force-closes the game without saving it. It's pretty much like crashing it.

Comment: @dly Alt+F4 regular closes it and saves the game, F3+C crashes it. I feel like Fabian Röling knows minecraft quite well, in this case he is my only source for the fact that Alt+F4 saves the game. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321540/232393 (And I have tried it myself a few times and I never got to reverse anyting with Alt+F4, even though I tried a few times and I were very quick)

Comment: @Mr.Bear the game gets saved regularly anyway, especially with block updates. Alt + F4 does not trigger another save. But if you interrupt a running save job with Alt + F4 you could lose that progress and possibly more than that.

Comment: @dly I am aware of that, I will probably do some testing later, or tomorrow, to understand saving mechanics a bit better. For now Fabian remains my only source, I couldn´t find anything else in a quick search.

Comment: @dly Interestingly after holding F3+C in 1.14.3, there was a save screen for a second indicating that the game is being saved. Saving appears to happen with Alt+F4, too, but I am not quite as sure yet and need to do some more testing. So far the game got saved with every attempt to close it with Alt+F4

Comment: @Mr.Bear perhaps its a topic for a new question altogether. Maybe someone else has reliable proof for expected behavior of those shortcuts.

Comment: @dly Neither Alt+F4, nor F3+C appear to close/crash the game without saving. Alt+F4 saves even simple changes, like moving a single block, or moving your mouse to rotate. Both were tried in a void world with only a small stone platform (superflat void preset). F3+C actually tells you that it saves.

Comment: I'm almost certain that F3+C copies your coordinates to the clipboard. It was a new feature added in either 1.13 or 1.14 I can't remember which one it was. I will test it again though when I get home from school today. Also I'm pretty sure the game auto saves every 2 seconds, if not 2 seconds than it might be 5-10 seconds but I'm pretty sure when you have optifine on and turn the autosave to default it changes to 2 seconds so that's why I think it is 2 seconds which is definitely not enough time to crash the game like that.

Comment: Ok I didn't realise you had said to 'hold' F3+C I was only thinking about when you press it without holding it so yeah I really have no idea

Comment: Backing up hardcore words defeats the point of them being hardcore.